# Check if object is a number or boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Design a logical expression equivalent to the following statement:
>
> `x` is a list of three or five elements, the second element of which is
>   the string `'Hip'` and the first of which is not a number or Boolean.

What I have:

```
x = ['Head', 'Hip', 10]
print x[1] is 'Hip'
```

My question: How do you check for whether or not it is a Boolean or a number?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

To answer the specific question:

```
isinstance(x[0], (int, float))
```

This checks if `x[0]` is an instance of any of the types in the tuple `(int, float)`.

You can add `bool` in there, too, but it's not necessary, because `bool` is itself a subclass of `int`.

Doc reference:

- [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)
- [built-in numeric types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)

---

To comment on your current code, you shouldn't rely on [interning of short strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). You are supposed to compare strings with the `==` operator:

```
x[1] == 'Hip'
```

Answer (score 50):

Easiest i would say:

```
type(x) == type(True)
```

Comment: A little bit hacky but no imports, so +1

Comment: Maybe directly `type(x) is bool`?

Comment: Using of `type` create a pylint message:  `C0123: Using type() instead of isinstance() for a typecheck. (unidiomatic-typecheck)`
Correct answer need to be the accepted one

Answer (score 38):

In python3 this would be: `type(x)==bool` see [example](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html).

Comment: Mine works in both. The logic is mostly language indepent as well.

Comment: `isinstance(x, bool)`

Answer (score 20):

Python 2

```
import types

x = False
print(type(x) == types.BooleanType) # True
```

Python 3

```
# No need to import types module
x = False
print(type(x) == bool) # True
```

Comment: `types.BooleanType` was removed from Python 3.  `bool` is used instead.  Source: http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#types

Answer (score 6):

You should compare the type of `x` to the `bool` class:

```
type(x) == bool
```

or:

```
type(x) == type(True)
```

Here is more on the [type method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

From [Data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> Booleans (bool)
>
> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I follow the recent answer who tell to use `type` and it seems to be the incorrect way according to `pylint` validation:

I got the message:

> C0123: Using type() instead of isinstance() for a typecheck.
>   (unidiomatic-typecheck)

Even if it's an old answer, the correct one is the accepted answer of @Lev Levitsky:

```
isinstance(x[0], (int, float))
```

Comment: pylint cannot know what you want to do. There is a difference between type() and isinstance() because isinstance() will also consider sub classes and type() will not. How can pylint know which one you need in your program? Check out this article on the differences: https://switowski.com/blog/type-vs-isinstance

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

Use `assert` to check is some statement is True or False. If False, it will raise an `AssertionError`.

```py
assert(isinstance(x[0], (int, float)))
```

You can then catch the error like that:

```py
except AssertionError as error:
    print(error)
    # do stuff...
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to keep it simple to read..
This will accept bool, string, number and read it to a bool

```
def var2bool(v):
if type(v) == type(True):
    res = v
elif type(v) == type(0):
    if v == 0:
        res = False
    else:
        res = True
elif v.lower() in ("yes", "true", "t", "1"):
    res = True
else:
    res = False
return res
```

Comment: Greetings from PEP8. "Object type comparisons should always use isinstance() instead of comparing types directly"