# Python - isinstance returns false

Tags: python, python-2.7, isinstance

I'm having an issue with `isinstance()`.

I'm using Python 2.7.8, and running scripts from the shell.

The `array` element I'm testing for contains a number, but this function returns false; using [`number.Numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html):

```
import numbers
...
print array[x][i] 
>> 1
...
print isinstance(array[x][i], numbers.Number)
>>> False
```

Also tried this, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204789/how-to-properly-use-pythons-isinstance-to-check-if-a-variable-is-a-number)

```
import types
...
print isinstance(array[x][i], (types.IntType, types.LongType, types.FloatType, types.ComplexType))
>>> False
```

From the same post, I tried

```
isinstance(array[x][i], (int, float, long, complex))
```

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019830/check-if-object-is-a-number-or-boolean) did not work.

All return false.

Comment: What does `print repr(array[x][i]), type(array[x][i])` produce?

Comment: what is the output of `type(array[x][i])` ?

Comment: You could have a *string* for example; if `array[x][i]` stores `'1'`, then `print` will produce that exact same output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a number; you *most probably* have a string instead, containing the *digit `'1'`*:

```
>>> value = '1'
>>> print value
1
>>> print 1
1
```

This is not a number; it is a string instead. Note that *printing* that string is indistinguishable from printing an integer.

Use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to print out *Python representations* instead, and / or use the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to produce the type object for a given value:

```
>>> print repr(value)
'1'
>>> print type(value)
<type 'str'>
```

Now it is clear that the value is a string, not an integer, even though it *looks* the same when printed.

For actual numeric values, `isinstance()` together with `numbers.Number` works as expected:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> isinstance(value, Number)
False
>>> isinstance(1, Number)
True
```

Comment: Thanks for putting that in context. It only looked like an integer.